# Как сделать вариативность ответа, зависящего от введенного слова

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Как сделать вариативность ответа, зависящего от введенного слова? (при использовании Tkinter, entry, get и if)

пример: нужно ввести в строку ввода слово лопата, слева от прямоугольника ввода должен располагаться текст "Введите название товара". Текст после ввода названия товара "лопата" должен смениться на стоимость+"числовая переменная". Значение этой переменной должно меняться при вводе других товаров ( например: кувшин, переменная поменяется на "500". стол - переменная станет "600").

Comment: Что вы уже пробовали сделать, что не получилось?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то я решил вашу проблему.
Вот полный код, удачи вам!

```
from tkinter import *

#Да я знаю что плохо знаю Английский язык :)

lopata = 300 # Стоимость лопаты

cuvshyn = 500 # Стоимость кувшина

table = 600 # Стоимость стола

#Создаем функцию "magazyn"  
def magazyn():
    # Это нужно для того, чтобы можно было получать как я понял данные из переменной 
"predmets"
    mtext = predmets.get()

    # А вот и условия
    if mtext == "Лопата":
        lab.config(text = "Стоимость: " + str(lopata))
    elif mtext == "Кувшин":
        lab.config(text = "Стоимость: " + str(cuvshyn))
    elif mtext == "Стол":
        lab.config(text = "Стоимость: " + str(table))
    else:
        lab.config(text = "У нас нет этого товара:(")
    return

# Ну а дальше, все по обычному
root = Tk()
predmets = StringVar()

root.geometry("450x450+500+300")
root.title("Магазин")

lab = Label(root, text = "Введите название товара: ")
lab.place(x = 10, y = 0)

but = Button(root, text = "Готово", command = magazyn, fg = "Black", bg = "Green")
but.place(x = 300, y = 0)

mEntry = Entry(root, textvariable = predmets)
mEntry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Да вам тоже, за практику:)